# javascript - How to randomly activate multiple cells in grid

Tags: javascript, css, grid, intervals

I work on one game and I stack in one problem. Look at code and test it.

```js
var createGrid=function(x,y){
     var arrY = new Array(),
      arrX,
            container = $(".table");
  i=1;
     for(var iy=0; iy<y; iy++){
      arrX = new Array();
      for(var ix=0; ix<x; ix++){
       arrX[ix]='<div class="cell">'+i+'</div>';
    i++;
      }
      arrY[iy]='<div class="row">'+arrX.join("\r\n")+'</div>';
     }
     container.append(arrY.join("\r\n"));
    };
// call function
(function($){
 // create grid
 createGrid(Math.ceil($(window).width()/50),Math.ceil($(window).height()/50));
 // setup on ready
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var cell= $(".cell"),
   maxCell = cell.length,
   // find random cell and setup
   randomActivate = function(){
     $(".cell.active").removeClass("active");
     var active=Math.round(Math.random()*(maxCell-1));
     cell.eq(active).addClass("active");
    };
   // start random cell
   randomActivate();
   // loop random cell
   setInterval(function(){
    randomActivate();
   }, 300);
 });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:-1px;
 clear:both;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}
.cell {display:table-cell; 
    border-right: 1px solid #000000; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 font-size:22px;
 font-weight:900;
 color:#FFF;
}
.row {
    display:table-row; 
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row:hover{
 background:#e9e9e9;
}
.row:hover>.cell{
 color:#e9e9e9;
}
.row>.cell:hover, .active{
 background:#f00;
}
.table {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 z-index:0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table"></div>
```

The problem where I stack is how to display in the same time multiple cells in grid?

For now, like you see, only one cell display number per interval. I need to add more intervals with different time what will made effect like randomly nasted numbers like show and hide. Is hard to explain becouse I can't find example.

In the same time can be more than one active cell but every interval to have control of own active cell.

You will have questions for me, please, shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `randomActivate` function starts with `$(".cell.active").removeClass("active");` which inactivates the currently active cell.

If you want to activate the entire grid in random order, just remove that call.

If you want something else, this is still where I'd recommend you to alter the code to suit your purposes.

Instead of removing the `active` class from all active cells like you are now, you could set a timeout to remove it from that specific class after some time, for instance.

- [Random reveal example](http://jsfiddle.net/wmxjse6o/)
  Here I also decrement `maxCell` on each iteration and use that to access an index not on all cells, but only on those that are not already active. Otherwise it could potentially take very long time until the last cell were to be randomized. I also stop the timeout when there are no inactive cells left.
- [Random timeouts example](http://jsfiddle.net/1b646L3g/)
  Here I am setting a random timeout for each activated cell, rather than removing all activated cells at all iterations.

If none of these are anywhere near your desired behavior, please specify in greater detail what you're after.

Comment: Random timeouts example is what I looking for. First solution I made in test but second is solution what I need.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to create another `randomActivate` function, like `randomActivate01` and have it light up other cells.

You can also apply a different `CSS` class to the cells lit up by the second `randomActivate` so you could have them appear yellow, or orange, instead of the same red.

Would that be the answer you are looking for?